# Proving that a minima exists in a function space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is bounded, fixed and piecewise continuous, and we minimize $\int g(x) f(x) d x$, with the constraint that $g$ is a pdf (it integrates to $1$, $\ge 0$), then how do we know that there is a $g$ that achieves the minima?

(For context this was in a computer science paper and I was confused about this part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not true.

Namely, let $f$ be a function with a strict global minimum point (say at $x=0$), e.g. $f(x) = \min\{0, |x| - 1\}$.

It's clear that, in order to minimize the integral, the mass of $g$ should be placed near to $0$.
Hence, you can construct a minimizing sequence $g_n$ converging to the Dirac delta at the origin. The infimum, however, is not achieved.

Comment: If you use the Cauchy Schwarz, $\int gf \ge - \| g\|_2 \cdot \| f\|_2$. So the functional is bounded below and the situation you described will not happen. Of course this is different from the original question, where one fixes $\int g = 1$ instead of $\int g^2  =1$. But I cannot see how you use the condition $\int g  = 1$.

Comment: I'm not saying that the functional is not bounded from below. Indeed, in my example, since $f\geq -1$ one has $\int f g \geq -\int g = -1$. This value $-1$ is actually the infimum over all probability distributions $g$, but it is not achieved.